# How to write select query using Linq to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

In my XDocument variable, I have XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><bases><base id="1" type="1"/><base id="2" type="2"/><base id="3" type="1"/></bases>
```

How should I write a query to select all bases?

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is full of examples how to do it...
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+xml+linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var bases = xDoc.Descendants("base")
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    Id= b.Attribute("id").Value,
                    Type = b.Attribute("type").Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: @Dmitry: you are so lucky the sof community is so helpful! :-)